# Adding colors to console log

Tags: javascript

How to make console.log colors work with multiple arguments?

***DOES NOT WORK:***

```
console.log('%cTEXT', 'color:orange', 'MORE \x1B[42m[TEXT]\033[39m: HERE')
```

***WORKS:***

```
console.log('MORE \x1B[42m[TEXT]\033[39m: HERE')
```

[Result of console.logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGmXO.png)

***DOES NOT WORK:***
**UPDATE**
Using replace on string fails.. Is this an encoding issue maybe?

```
let a = "this is a [string] blah"
let replacedStr = a.replace(/(\[\w+\])/g, function (match, p1) {
  return '%c' + p1 + '%c'
})
let replaceStrWithColor = [replacedStr, 'color:red;color:reset']

console.log.call(console, '%csomething', 'color:green', ...replaceStrWithColor)
```

If you run the above example you will see "something" is green and the output: `something this is a %c[string]%c blah color:red;color:reset`

Comment: I believe it is still unclear what the wanted result is. Please say specifically what  inputs and outputs do you want

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` formatter consumes *arguments* from left to right, with each argument (after the first) indicating the formatting to be applied at the corresponding *specifier* in the text. So if you want multiple CSS properties to be applied at different points in the text, just put the necessary `%c` *specifiers* in the text and match it with the same number of *arguments* for formatting. Each formatting argument will take effect from the point its specifier appears onward.

```
console.log('%cRed %cGreen %cBlue', "color:red", "color:green", "color:blue");
```

Edit, it's really unclear what you are trying to do here. I think you're trying to change color and substitute strings at the same time? If so, that is totally possible, but the string replacement *specifier* is a different one than that for color (`%s` instead of `%c`).

```
console.log(
  '%c%s %c%s %c%s',
  "color:red",
  "string replacement (red)",
  "color:green",
  "string replacement (green)",
  "color:blue",
  "string replacement (blue)"
);
```

[image]

1. The first `%c` sets "color:red" as the CSS style
2. The first `%s` swaps out for "string replacement (red)"
3. The second `%c` sets "color:green" as the CSS style
4. The second `%s` swaps out for "string replacement (green)"
5. etc...

Note how each *specifier* in the string is matched, ***in order***, with each *argument* to `console.log` after the first one (the first argument being the string perform formatting upon).

If this isn't clear still I think you need to add much more clarity to your original post or just try reading up on/practicing this pattern a bit more.

https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter

Comment: hey jered - thanks I also tried this and it does work. but I have a replace text function and a call to console.log and this fails.. Let me update my question.

Comment: @LordBear updated my answer. If this is still unclear I think you are just misunderstanding how to use `console.log` with formatting specifiers. Try reading https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console more

Comment: Yes closer.. but I'm trying to color just a substr. In your example -- for instance make the green replacement pink. Doesn't seem possible by defining the colors/str in front `'%c%s %c%s %c%s',`

Comment: doesn't seem possible as per the spec - I would need to split the str

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is because the first use of [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) uses an invalid amount of args for the substitution string.

Maybe this is what you are looking for?...

```
console.log('MORE \x1B[42m[%s]\033[39m: HERE', 'TEXT');
```

---

Is following not good enough? I still don't get exactly what you are trying to achieve...

```js
let a = "this is a [string] blah"
let replacedStr = a.replace(/(\[\w+\])/g, function (match, p1) {
  return '\x1B[42m' + p1 + '\033[39m:';
});
console.log(replacedStr);
```

Do you want to use the `color:orange` syntax?

---

## Another edit

I think I understand what you want. You want to pass a number of strings and for each string, apply a different color. You have no choice but to have **1 string**, that will contain all your sub-strings, followed by the colors for each sub-string:

```
let stringsToColor = ["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps overthe lazy", "dog"];
console.log('%c' + stringsToColor.join('%c '), 'color:purple', 'color:yellow', 'color:brown', 'color:orange', 'color:reset', 'color:blue');
```

You could try and reduce the ugliness of this code by doing something like this:

```
let coloredStrings = [
    {str: 'The', color: 'purple'}
    , {str: 'quick', color: 'reset'}
    , {str: 'brown', color: 'brown'}
    /*etc*/
];
console.log(
    coloredStrings.map(val => '%c' + val.str).join(' '), 
    ...coloredStrings.map(val => `color:${val.color};`)
);
```

However, you will have to handle the contents of your string first, to get the array you need.